# Formula won't copying with reference because it links to another file

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using Excel 2013 and have run into an issue. I have large amounts of information to go through with only a single repetitive way to do it. I am using the formula `=rept()` which links to another file. I have to do this for over 10 columns and over 2500 rows and each cell I have to remake the formula manually.

Usually if you copy a formula into another row or column the information will change according to where you put it but this formula, but it will not do this since it is linking to another file. I have this way of doing it where I have to select each row individually and then use find and replace with the row I want it to repeat because it wont cross reference the rows automatically.

This is very annoying and repetitive, please help.

Comment: Not sure I understand your issue. Are you copying 2500 rows x 10 columns of data from one sheet to another?  If so, why do you not use paste special and do it in one step?  If there is a formula used to transpose the data somehow, why not make a MyFormula in the name manager with the correct references and use it as a single step solution?

Comment: Your question has a bit of the XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to accomplish? I'm going to give you an answer based on what I'm guessing you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a set of data that needs to exist in multiple spreadsheets, but you want to maintain a single master copy.

The straightforward way to do this is to "Paste Link."

Open the master copy, select the range of cells, and hit Copy. You can future-proof this a little by selecting currently empty cells that you expect to be populated in the future. The downside is that they'll show up as `0` in the destination spreadsheet.

From the same instance of Excel, open your destination spreadsheet and select the top-left cell of the destination. Click on the triangle under the **Paste** icon for additional options and choose **Paste Special**. In the Paste Special dialog, click on the **Paste Link** button.

You'll end up with a range of cells populated with the basic formula `='[Master Sheet.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1`.

After doing this, if you realize that there are more rows or columns to bring over, you can select the last row or column and then drag the corner to auto-fill additional rows or columns.

Comment: This did the job perfectly, thank you very much.